# REST API how can I obtain my data from a POST URL?

Tags: java, rest, client

I am creating my first REST API using java to accept a post request and insert it to a postgresql database. I have a simple command line program that successfully posts and gets data from a database. The command line prompt asks "Do you want to get or set" you choose, and then either insert or get data. Now I want to know, how can I retrieve this data from a post URL to set in the database?

I want to be able to insert new data to the database when when a function sends a JSON to my url.. Right now, the command line looks like this:

```
Do you want to get or set a person's info?
(Type 'get' or 'set' now.)
set
Provide information...
first name: bob
email: bob@test.com
last name: builder
policy number: 143
premium: 34234
carrier: neptune
customerPolicyType: new
modified date: 010101
created date: 0305032
POST was successful.
```

Then after obtaining the information, it goes to this function and inserts to the database.

```
public static void setPersonData(Person p) throws MalformedURLException, IOException {
    
    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL("http://localhost:8080/happycoding/people/" + p.getfName()).openConnection();

    connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
    
    String postData = "first_name=" + URLEncoder.encode(p.getfName());
    postData += "&email=" + URLEncoder.encode(p.getEmail());
    postData += "&last_name=" + URLEncoder.encode(p.getlName());
    //postData += "&id=" + p.getId();
    postData += "&policy_number=" + URLEncoder.encode(p.getPolicyNumber());
    postData += "&premium=" + URLEncoder.encode(p.getPremium());
    postData += "&carrier=" + URLEncoder.encode(p.getCarrier());
    postData += "&cutomer_policy_type=" + URLEncoder.encode(p.getCustomerPolicyType());
    postData += "&modified_date=" + URLEncoder.encode(p.getModifiedDate());
    postData += "&created_date=" + URLEncoder.encode(p.getCreatedDate());
    
    
    connection.setDoOutput(true);
    OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());
    wr.write(postData);
    wr.flush();
    
    int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
    if(responseCode == 200){
        System.out.println("POST was successful.");
    }
    else if(responseCode == 401){
        System.out.println("Error.");
    }

}
```

My plan is to receive the data to set from an online workflow and function that will send me the information that I am currently requesting by user input. Then send that information to my URL which will then insert it to the database. Please point me in the right direction on how I can do this.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a row in postgres using a POST API where your additional "get" or "set" data should be optional in fields. Then expose an "UPDATE" API and get the additional data in payload to update the same row.